# How to localize Fabric events text

Tags: google-fabric

I am using Fabric events to record some events, the content of event is using other language instead of English, it is displayed as some sort of wrong encoded text from Fabric portal(Fabric.io), unreadable. How can we solve this issue? Thanks a lot.